# Post ajax data to MVC controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following ajax in a .chtml file:

```
    var planID = $("#PlanID").val();
    if (planID.length == 4) {
        $(ctl).prop("disabled", true).text(msg);
        $("#nextButton").prop("disabled", true);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".submit-progress").removeClass("hidden");
        }, 1);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ForgotUserID/CheckPlanID",
            data: '{planID: "' + planID + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("ajax success function");
                $("form").submit();
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
        //$("form").submit()
    }
```

And I have the following in my ForgotUserIDController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CheckPlanID(string planID)
    {
        ForgotUserID forgotUserID = new ForgotUserID()
        {
            PlanID = planID
        };

        return Json(forgotUserID);
    }
```

When I run the code, I see this in the dev tools under network:

[image]

So I know the data that I typed into my input box is floating around somewhere.

When I have a breakpoint set in my controller, the value of planID is null. Shouldn't the value get passed from the ajax data component?

How can I get the data typed into the input box passed to my controller?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What error is returned from the server? My guess is that the error is because you're setting the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` but your controller is likely expecting a text media type such as `text/html` or `text/plain` since you're requiring a `string` as an argument.

Comment: If this is the case, there are 3 solutions I can think of off the top of my head. The first would be to change the media type to a `text` type and parse the JSON on the backend. This isn't really the best solution, but would work. The second would be to create a model with a string property called `planID` and use that as the argument for the endpoint method. The last option would be to ditch JSON altogether and just pass the ID by itself.

Comment: There is no error being returned from the server as far as I can tell.  I tried changing the dataType to text and also text/plain.  I still get null in the controller but I still see {planID: "XXXX"} in the request payload under dev tools/network.

Comment: I'm meaning the HTTP error code. It gives you a general idea of what's wrong. In your screenshot the request is red meaning a 4xx or 5xx error code was returned from the server.

Comment: it looks like I'm getting this: POST https://localhost:5001/ForgotUserID/CheckPlanID net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Comment: @Jesse I got this to work.  Maybe its something with MVC but I changed all the references in the view from planID to PlanID to match the definition of PlanID in the model that gets passed to the view and now the value from the input box gets passed to the controller.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes. If you use a model as the input parameter then the names of the fields in the JSON object that gets sent needs to exactly match the name of the property in your model exactly. It is case sensitive.

Comment: Try change this part. I guess your syntax is incorect.  data:{ planID: planID,},

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

fix ajax data line

```
 data: JSON.stringify({ planID : planID  }),
```

and create viewmodel and use frombody attribute in action

```
 public JsonResult CheckPlanID([FromBody] PlanViewModel model)
{
       string planID=model.PlanID;
      ....
}

public class PlanViewModel
{
  public string PlanID {get;set;}
}
```

or  remove  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" and fix data

```
//contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

data: { planID : planID  },
```

in this case you don't need and extra class and frombody attribute. Leave your action header as it is